# Windows Query session states

Tags: windows

What are all of the possible session states in windows? (example: Disc, Active, etc.) I haven't been able to find documentation suggesting the possible values, or a standard on what the values could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383860) that you can get from `WTSQuerySessionInformation` documents these values:

```
WTSActive,
WTSConnected,
WTSConnectQuery,
WTSShadow,
WTSDisconnected,
WTSIdle,
WTSListen,
WTSReset,
WTSDown,
WTSInit
```

(`WTSActive` is 0, `WTSConnected` is 1 and so on)

Answer (score 4):

Combining both information from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/ne-wtsapi32-_wts_connectstate_class) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c51f67eb-1ed6-46fc-9b9f-212b2c8ae132/how-to-see-query-session-result-?forum=winservergen) (**Query** and *WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS* representation):

- **Active** (*WTSActive*) : The session is connected and active. (*A user is logged on to the WinStation*).
- **Conn** (*WTSConnected*) : The session is connected. No user is logged on. (*The WinStation is connected to the client*).
- **ConnQ** (*WTSConnectQuery*) : The session is in the process of connecting. If this state continues, it indicates a problem with the connection. (*The WinStation is in the process of connecting to the client*).
- **Shadow** (*WTSShadow*) : The session is shadowing another session. (*The WinStation is shadowing another WinStation*).
- **Listen** (*WTSListen*) : The session is ready to accept a client connection. (T*he WinStation is listening for a connection. A listener session waits for requests for new client connections. No user is logged on a listener session. A listener session cannot be reset, shadowed, or changed to a regular client session*).
- **Disc** (*WTSDisconnected*) : The session is disconnected. (*The WinStation is active but the client is disconnected*).
- **Idle** (*WTSIdle*) : The session is initialized. (*The WinStation is waiting for a client to connect*).
- **Down** (*WTSDown*) : The session is down, indicating the session failed to initialize correctly. (*The WinStation is down due to an error*).
- **Init** (*WTSInit*) : The session is initializing. (*The WinStation is initializing*).